# Hadoop : Datanodes not starting

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm learning how to set up Hadoop environment using AWS free tier (Ubuntu 20.04.2) 4 nodes and when I type : start-dfs.sh on my name node it's doesn't start the data nodes for some reasons :

[image]

Logs :

```
2021-10-24 12:46:46,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
2021-10-24 12:46:46,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
2021-10-24 12:46:46,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.top.metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
2021-10-24 12:46:46,929 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Checkpoint Period   :3600 secs (60 min)
2021-10-24 12:46:46,929 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Log Size Trigger    :1000000 txns
2021-10-24 12:46:46,951 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil: Starting Web-server for secondary at: http://0.0.0.0:9868
2021-10-24 12:46:47,018 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @6209ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2021-10-24 12:46:47,419 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2021-10-24 12:46:47,448 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.secondary is not defined
2021-10-24 12:46:47,469 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2021-10-24 12:46:47,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context secondary
2021-10-24 12:46:47,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2021-10-24 12:46:47,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2021-10-24 12:46:47,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 9868
2021-10-24 12:46:47,605 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.20.v20190813; built: 2019-08-13T21:28:18.144Z; git: 84700530e645e812b336747464d6fbbf370c9a20; jvm 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04
2021-10-24 12:46:47,725 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-10-24 12:46:47,725 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-10-24 12:46:47,726 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2021-10-24 12:46:47,780 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d868997{logs,/logs,file:///usr/local/hadoop/logs/,AVAILABLE}
2021-10-24 12:46:47,784 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3af37506{static,/static,file:///usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/static/,AVAILABLE}
2021-10-24 12:46:48,186 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@783efb48{secondary,/,file:///usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/secondary/,AVAILABLE}{file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/secondary}
2021-10-24 12:46:48,233 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@7f9e1534{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9868}
2021-10-24 12:46:48,233 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @7424ms
2021-10-24 12:46:48,233 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Web server init done
```

I've already tried to delete the tmp files and re format my namenode but same issue..

PS : I'm using hadoop 3.2.2

Comment: 1) Just use EMR 2) Show the logs from running `hadoop datanode` by itself

Comment: I don't know if it normal or not but it's empty

Comment: Hmmm. Are you able to find a logs folder in the hadoop home path, or under /var/log that has just a datanode log file?

Comment: in the hadoop home path : /usr/local/hadoop/logs, i've tried to launch hadoop stand alone on every nodes and its worked fine but when i tried on the 4 nodes there is something wrong wih the secondary node i guess but the logs don't give us lot of informations

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by downgrading to hadoop 2.10.1 .